# Trying to let the user import .csv files into my app

Tags: android, file, csv, android-intent, import

When you want to *export* a .csv, I got it to work after writing this code:

```
Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
sendIntent.setType("text/csv|text/comma-separated-values|application/csv");
String[] mimetypes = {"text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values", "application/csv"};
sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
sendIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, arrayListOfUris);
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sendIntent, "Export CSV"));
```

When you run this code, it brings up a little chooser dialog where you can export the files into GMail, Email, Android Beam, DropBox, Google Drive, etc. And it appears to work fine with multiple files.

However, trying to accomplish the reverse (receiving multiple .csv files) has proven to be really, really hard. And I've read so many StackOverflow threads and they're either outdated or they don't actually solve the problem.

I have been trying this:

```
Intent receiveIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
receiveIntent.setType("text/csv|text/comma-separated-values|application/csv");
String[] mimetypes = {"text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values", "application/csv"};
receiveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
intent.addCategory(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE);
startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(receiveIntent, "Import CSV"), REQUEST_IMPORT_CSV); //REQUEST_IMPORT_CSV is just an int representing a request code for the activity result callback later
```

However this only brings up a chooser that says there is no app that can complete this task, which I find baffling.

If I remove the `EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` line, then I get two outcomes:

1. If I run the app from an emulator, it goes to a file explorer where I can select a single file. As far as I can tell, that works and all, but doesn't allow me to pick multiple files.
2. If I run the app from my physical phone, it doesn't open the file explorer -- it gives me the option to import from DropBox or some other app that isn't really relevant.

Why isn't it allowing the file explorer? Why isn't it allowing other options like Google Drive for example? Is there really no service for importing multiple files into your app? Does it only give you the file explorer when it can't find any other app to invoke?

My end goal here is to basically prompt the user with a chooser that lets them pick one or more .csv files from either an external app like DropBox, or from their own file system via a file explorer.

Or is my code wrong somehow?

What do I do? The Android documentation offers no help on the matter.

Edit: My emulator phone is a Galaxy Nexus API 23 and a Nexus 5 API 22. My physical phone is a Samsung Galaxy Note 4 (version 6.0.1).

Comment: Since `setType()` is not documented to support a pipe-delimited, list, change both` setType()` calls to provide a single MIME type, and see if that helps.

Comment: @CommonsWare Problem is I don't know which one is the correct one. Most online answers say to use `text/csv` but then in the file explorer, the `csv` files are greyed out. I can only select them if I use `text/comma-separated-values` for some reason. But since `text/csv` is used everywhere else I figured I'd try to include all three.

Comment: "Problem is I don't know which one is the correct one" -- pick one. "I'd try to include all three" -- that is [via `EXTRA_MIME_TYPES`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_MIME_TYPES), for Android 4.4+.

Comment: So something like `receiveIntent.setType("text/comma-separated-values");` then 
`String[] mimetypes = {"text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values", "application/csv"};` then 
`receiveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);` ?

Comment: Testing it now, if I use just one type, the outcome is the same whether I use `text/csv` or `text/comma-separated-values` or `application/csv` on my physical device.

Comment: Also, try getting rid of `Intent.createChooser()`. You might also wish to edit your question and explain exactly what Android OS versions you are testing on.

Comment: Edited. Also removing the chooser doesn't change anything.

Comment: [`EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE` is an extra key](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE). It is not a category. If you use it, you `putExtra()`, providing a boolean value, not `addCategory()`.

Comment: Using `receiveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_ALLOW_MULTIPLE, true);` correctly allows me to select multiple .csv files from my emulator's file explorer, but on my physical phone, it's still only showing things like DropBox (and no file explorer).

Comment: Perhaps Samsung changed some stuff. `ACTION_GET_CONTENT` is principally for pre-Android 4.4. Consider supporting `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` on Android 4.4+.

Comment: Is there a way to support both?

Comment: If you mean based on OS version, use `Build.VERSION.SDK_INT`. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/blob/v8.0/Documents/Consumer/app/src/main/java/com/commonsware/android/documents/consumer/ConsumerFragment.java#L128-L137

Comment: If I use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` it only shows me one app to use to do the importing ("Documents") and clicking it goes to my file system on my phone. Which is good because now it uses the file system, but now it no longer displays things like Dropbox.

Comment: Dropbox apparently has not implemented a storage provider yet. The point behind `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` was to allow Dropbox and others to plug storage providers into the framework, so the user could get to their contents as easily as the user could get to the filesystem.

Comment: But if that's true, then Google Drive hasn't implemented one, GMail hasn't implemented one, etc -- there is apparently no other app on my phone that has this implemented.

Comment: I would not expect an email client to implement a storage provider. Google Drive is a natural fit functionality-wise, but I do not use it, so I have no idea what they have or have not implemented.

Comment: What do most people use nowadays outside of Google Drive and Dropbox? I thought those two were the big ones in terms of storage providers.

Comment: Beats me. And, in my comments, by "storage provider" I specifically mean [an implementation of `DocumentsProvider`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/DocumentsProvider.html), as part of support for [the Storage Access Framework](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/document-provider.html).

Comment: Google Drive honors ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT and ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT. But not ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.

Comment: @greenaps Google Drive doesn't appear to support ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT because it doesn't show up in the app chooser when I launch that Intent

Comment: @CommonsWare According to what I am reading online in other places, there's a lot of disappointment over the Storage Access Framework because apparently a lot of apps don't implement it yet, even big/popular ones

Comment: There is a lot of disappointment over a lot of things in the Android SDK.

Comment: Haha, can't argue with that!

Comment: @CommonsWare Is there a similar newer way for sending files other than `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`? I want to let the user choose either the file system or another app for exporting, like what Dropbox does: http://bestusefultips.ghanshyamsheladi.netdna-cdn.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/How-to-export-files-from-dropbox-to-android-phone.jpg

Comment: "Is there a similar newer way for sending files other than `ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE`?" -- not for multiple pieces of content ("files").

Comment: But somehow DropBox is able to do it?

Comment: `Google Drive doesn't appear to support ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT because it doesn't show up in the app chooser when I launch that Intent`. You do not have to repeat that as i already knew. That very statement was the reason i posted my experience. So why we have different results? Android version? Device manufacturer?

Comment: `But somehow DropBox is able to do it? `. Sorry for the confusion. No Dropbox not. Dropbox will only appear with ACTION_GET_CONTENT. (found the device back and tried it out).

Answer (score 2):

The following works for me

```
receiveIntent.setType("*/*");
String[] mimetypes = {"text/csv", "text/comma-separated-values", "application/csv"};
receiveIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_MIME_TYPES, mimetypes);
```